# Get data from 2 observables inside resolver

Tags: angular

I have a few services that are working with the observable principle. I want to get the results of 2 services inside a resolver to use at my page. But the result inside the page is just a empty data object. I have also tried `first()` instead of `take(1)`, but no difference there.

My resolver:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private companyResolver: CompanyService, private countryService: CountryService, private genderService: GenderService) { }


  resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ) {

    return forkJoin({
      countries: this.countryService.getCountries().pipe(take(1)),
      genders: this.genderService.getGenders().pipe(take(1)),
    });
  }
}
```

My page:

```
export class SettingsCompanyOverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public countryService: CountryService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  } 
}
```

Service:

```
export class CountryService {

  private countryObserver$: BehaviorSubject<CountryInterface[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) {
    this.getData();
  }

  getCountries(): Observable<GenderInterface[]> {
    return this.countryObserver$.asObservable();
  }

  private getData(): void {
    this.apiService.get<CountryInterface[]>(ApiRoutes.getCountries, null).then(res => {
      this.countryObserver$.next(res);
    });
  }
}
```

I don't get what is going wrong as I really expect data from both services.

Edit: It seems that the first data from the observable is empty, after that I get the expected results. I thought that `BehaviorSubject` gives the last result back?

Comment: Do you have a common service? a shared service?

Comment: @Lenzman they are a shared service

Comment: Yes, you are rigth,BehaviorSubject its created with initial value , the firs time you subscribe to BehaviorSubject, it's emit that initial value, the other time you subscribe to it, it's emite the last value it have. You should evaluate your scenario and define if that is what you want, or only get value emited after subscribe using Subject instead of BehaviorSubject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As established in comment, BehaviorSubject emits the initial value in the resolver, because it takes some time for the http-request to complete, but by then, when new value would be emitted, the resolver has already done its job.

Looks to me that you wouldn't need the behaviorSubject as a middleman? You could assign it directly to an observable. If you need to share same data, you can use `shareReplay` which just emits the value without making a http request. So something like this for the country service:

```ts
export class CountryService {

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  countries$ = this.getData().pipe(shareReplay());

  private getData(): Observable<CountryInterface[]> {
    return this.apiService.get<CountryInterface[]>(ApiRoutes.getCountries, null)
  }
}
```

Then in your resolver, just listen to `countries$` instead of your BehaviorSubject.

```ts
return forkJoin({
  countries: this.countryService.countries$.pipe(take(1)),
  //....
});
```

You can apply the same for your other service like I did above for the country service.